# How do I searchsorted row by row with respect to corresponding rows in another array

Tags: python, numpy

consider the arrays `a` and `b`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
a = np.random.choice(np.arange(100), (2, 10), False)
b = np.random.choice(np.arange(100), (2, 10), False)
a.sort(1)
b.sort(1)
print(a, '\n' * 2, b)

[[ 3 20 21 46 47 61 80 83 88 94]
 [ 1 16 32 33 40 48 57 59 69 84]] 

[[32 38 44 50 52 63 68 82 93 95]
 [ 3 25 27 37 57 62 71 78 85 86]]
```

I can do a `np.searchsorted` of `b[0]` on `a[0]`

```
print(a[0].searchsorted(b[0]))

[ 3  3  3  5  5  6  6  7  9 10]
```

But how do I do all rows at once?